# How can I change only those variables that are exists in JSON

Tags: python, jquery, flask, socket.io

I have a python flask app that receives data from the website with socket.io. From the website I can send apprx. 30 values in json and there is a function in python which is triggered when it receives the json.  I do not want to send them all every time if any of them changes or write separate python function (`@socket.on..... def....`) for each value. So basically I wish to construct the json dinamically then process the json with one function and leave the python variables unchanged if they are not exists or null in the json.

How can I do it? Shall I use `"try...: except NameError:"` for each key in the list if it exists and pass if not?

Thank you

Comment: `if name in dictionary: do_something`

Comment: Thank you. I thought that there is a shorter way than writing 30 if statement, but it is looks better and shorter than writing those I mentioned.

Comment: you can try to use list and `for`-loop  ie `for name in [....list...]: if name in dictionary:...`

Comment: if every name need to run different function then you could keep it as dictionary `{name1: function_name1, name2: function_name2, ..}` and use `for name, func in {name1: function_name1,...}: if name in dict: func()`

Comment: Well, thank you. I will use for loop it is a great idea.